# Nested XML in POST data gets parsed by 3rd party app, how to prevent that?

Tags: xml, parsing

I am trying to use an API to update some things in an application.  It takes the data as XML.  One of the required fields actually stores XML.  I am having some issues.  If someone can think of a better name for this post or better tags, please update it... that's the best I could do.

Starting in the DB (`prfx_xml` is valid xml):

```
PRFX_ID       PRFX_NAME        PRFX_XML
1             thing_one        <stuff><idk>123</idk><val>ABC</val></stuff>
```

What I need to send as XML....

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<entry xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">   
    <ns:PRFX.update xmlns:tes="http://www.zzz.com/client/nsservlet"> 
            <ns:id>1</ns:id>
            <ns:name>thing_one</ns:name>
            <ns:xmldata>
                <stuff><idk>123</idk><val>ABC</val></stuff>  <!-- This needs to be stored as a string value in the DB -->
            </ns:xmldata>
        </ns:PRFX> 
    </ns:PRFX.update> 
</entry>
```

The XML is encoded as ISO-8859-1 before it is sent.  I assume the application decodes it and then parses the XML.  When it does this, **it is also parsing out the `xmldata` field**.  When this post hits the database, I am left with:

```
PRFX_ID       PRFX_NAME        PRFX_XML
1             thing_one        123ABC
```

What do I do?  **How do I force it to receive that as a string?**  I have access to the back end of the third party application but it is in Java and I wouldn't even know where to start with all the .jar's and .war's.  My knowledge of XML is limited.  Would adding a namespace help?  Would the application still understand what it was getting?  If I use quotes, it literally stores the quotes in the DB.  I tried encoding the nested XML separately but that didn't work, either.

Ideas?

Comment: Also... yes, I must go through the API.  I cannot just update the database unfortunately.

Comment: What does the API want to do with the XML you are sending it? In fact, what format does it want?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - So.. it's REST.  It wants it in the format I am sending it in.  It successfully accepts and uses what is above.  However, I need that XML field stored as XML.  I think when the XML gets parsed on the other end, it parses that nested value, too.  When I check the DB, all the tags are gone (from the nested value). If I put it in quotes, it stores the quotes.  I need a way of telling it to treat the value for `xmldata` as a string, not more XML.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you're sending it in the right format, but you say you want to change the format. Is it possible that the API has a bug, or that you're not actually sending in the correct format? Maybe you need to send it as CDATA?

Comment: I'm googling cdata.  Maybe?  I think I just completely killed the app on our test server, though, because it can't parse the data currently in the field.........

Comment: I would check again to see exactly what format they want that XML column to be in, and exactly what they say they will do with the data in that column.

Comment: The documentation is extremely limited.  It just says string and does not provide an example of updating anything or using `'PRFX'` things.  Based on errors I saw in the beginning, it is used to create some kind of object based on the xml (so if you don't pass all the right tags, it rejects the update).

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I bet you're just sending the wrong XML format. You've gotten close enough that it doesn't reject the update, but not close enough that it puts the right data into the database.

Comment: (I can't believe I just broke the thing, I've never broken anything this big before... the whole app won't run).  Umm... so, last question... is CDATA what people normally do/use for something like that?

Comment: There's no "normal". It depends on what the application wants.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - just post that as an answer and i accept it...... thanks for the info.  i consider it an answer... that or my question needs to be closed as too localized. (trying not to keep posting comments)

Comment: I would, but I don't consider that to be an answer.

Comment: Heyyy, the app runs again after stopping/starting a few services!  I asked permission to break it again (since we can apparently fix it, too).  Anything besides CDATA that I could try?

Comment: You could try to get better documentation or examples, but other than that, not really. Assuming it really wants XML. I suppose the other guess would be to encode it, replacing `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;`, `'` with `&amp;` and `"` with `&quot;`

Comment: ridiculous.  you're right. `CDATA` worked instantly.  now, please post as answer...?   all I had to do was `<![CDATA[<stuff>...</stuff>]]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that the service appears to be looking inside the XML you're sending, I suggest that you try surrounding it with CDATA, to keep the service from looking inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<entry xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">   
    <ns:PRFX.update xmlns:tes="http://www.zzz.com/client/nsservlet"> 
            <ns:id>1</ns:id>
            <ns:name>thing_one</ns:name>
            <ns:xmldata>
                <![CDATA[<stuff><idk>123</idk><val>ABC</val></stuff>]]>
            </ns:xmldata>
        </ns:PRFX> 
    </ns:PRFX.update> 
</entry>
```

This is just a guess, though. The correct action in this case is to find out what the service wants to see.